# Getting the ID from the Route data in ASP.NET 5 API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

I'm implementing an ASP.NET 5 API where I have the following POST method:

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
   // Do something
)
```

For me to process the request, I need both the ID and the string value which will be in the body.

I realize that I can also put the ID in the body but I was wondering if there's a way for me to get the ID directly from the route data -- like in MVC 4/5 where I'd use the following syntax:

```
var id = (string)this.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

What's the best way for me to get the ID value in ASP.NET 5? Use the code above or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decorate your parameter with `[FromRoute]`:

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public void Post([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] string value) {
   // Do something
)
```

Comment: I'm receiving both an Id and a string value. I'll get the string value from the body so I need [FromBody] to grab the string value. Question is how to get the id from the route.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!